# Does CygWin and Windows Powershell return the approximate correct (real, user and sys) time for program, like the time command utility in Linux do?

Tags: powershell, cygwin

Can we calculate the (real, user and sys) time for the C program in Windows using Cygwin and Powershell, like we do in Linux using time command utility ?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell has a built in command that is similar to Bash's "time". It is called `Measure-Command`.

You can use it like this:

```
Measure-Command {echo ok}
```

The output will be:

```
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 0
Ticks             : 1318
TotalDays         : 1.52546296296296E-09
TotalHours        : 3.66111111111111E-08
TotalMinutes      : 2.19666666666667E-06
TotalSeconds      : 0.0001318
TotalMilliseconds : 0.1318
```

Comment: How to get (real, user and sys) time using this information. ?

Comment: @KhushalGupta sorry, no idea about that